# Are SSE messages encrypted over an https connection?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, nginx, https, server-sent-events

Say I configured my NGINX server with SSL and
I am able to establish and keep a server sent events connection
to my Rails server.
Would every message from thereon from Rails to my browser be
undecipherable to any prying eyes on the Internet.
Moreover would I be even able to establish such a connection? Since all I hear is that SSE works over http.

Comment: Wireshark will show you what is happening.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

Be aware that connecting from an http html page to an https SSE URL counts as a different *origin*, meaning you will hit CORS restrictions.

According to a footnote in my book (Data Push Apps With HTML5 SSE) Chrome was not accepting self-signed SSL certificates for use with SSE, as of early 2014. (But it was also not accepting them for XMLHttpRequest, i.e. ajax, either.)  (A quick search shows people still posting bug reports about self-signed certificates not working, so this might still be the case.)